# "ComputedDate"'s interpretation of "next"

Tags: date-and-time, interpreter

```
Today
```

[image]

```
Interpreter["ComputedDate"] /@ {"next Monday", "next Tuesday", "next Wednesday"}
```

[image]

What explains this behavior? Can it be controlled?

Comment: In all fairness, `Interpreter` documentation says "applied to a string *to try* to interpret..." What makes you believe its output should always be correct?

Comment: That language obviously refers to the fact that the function can only recognize a finite number of patterns. There is only one type of pattern being submitted here and it is exhibiting inconsistent behavior; I did not say it was incorrect but rather asked if there was an explanation. Clearly "next" is a relative concept depending on when the week starts, so for all I know it is a timezone issue.

Comment: I was joking, welcome to a new kind of speculative science. I don't think it's a TZ issue, try more days.

Comment: My bad, went over my head. Days Wednesday and forward are shifted shifted a week ahead as of today (Sunday).

Comment: @mfvonh Have you tried "this" over "next". People have argued about definition of this Monday vs next Monday. Even Interpreter["ComputedDate"] /@ {"this Monday", "this Tuesday", 
  "this Wednesday"} is ambiguous. Try "current".

Answer (score 2):

As @Hans pointed out in a comment, this isn't as straightforward to interpret as it may seem. Take a look at this question from english.stackexchange: ["Which day does “next Tuesday” refer to?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3841/which-day-does-next-tuesday-refer-to). The English language is a complex beast!

> To me, “next Tuesday” means the Tuesday that comes next week. For
> example, on Monday, October 11 and Wednesday, October 13, “next
> Tuesday” means October 19. Whereas on Monday, October 18, “next
> Tuesday” means October 26. “This Tuesday” refers to the Tuesday that
> comes this week, which on Wednesday would refer to yesterday, and on
> Monday refers to tomorrow. Similarly, “Last Tuesday” is the Tuesday
> that came last week.
>
> Without any descriptors, day names by themselves
> mean the next such day in the future unless used in the past tense.
> “He will do it on Tuesday” means the next time there is a Tuesday,
> which on Monday would mean “tomorrow” but on Wednesday would mean the
> following Tuesday. In the past tense, day names mean the last such day
> which occurred. “He did it on Tuesday” means the most recent day that
> was a Tuesday.

This alternative is perhaps a bit easier to interpret, and the results it returns make sense to me. You could also use `"current Monday"` etc.

```
Today
(* Mon 13 Apr 2015 *)

Interpreter["ComputedDate"] /@ {"this Monday", "this Tuesday", 
  "this Wednesday", "this Thursday", "this Friday", "this Saturday", 
  "this Sunday"}
```

[image]

However, returning to your example using the word "next", quite why the change occurs between Thursday 23rd and Friday 17th April I don't know.

```
Interpreter["ComputedDate"] /@ {"next Monday", "next Tuesday", 
  "next Wednesday", "next Thursday", "next Friday", "next Saturday", 
  "next Sunday"}
```

[image]

Another thing to try is the following. It seems that the new week is interpreted to start on a Sunday.

```
Interpreter["ComputedDate"] /@ {"Monday next week", 
  "Tuesday next week", "Wednesday next week", "Thursday next week", 
  "Friday next week", "Saturday next week", "Sunday next week"}
```

[image]